# Why when I select FFmpeg option for rendering a video the encoding tab does not showing up?

Tags: rendering, animation, encoding

I'm trying to render an animation in blender 2.79
I have selected FFmpeg video in output and I need to select codecs etc but there is no encoding tab showing up under this but only freestyle. please help!!

Comment: Have you checked all of the tabs in the properties area? Maybe the encoding tab got moved. If it really is nowhere have you tried restarting Blender? Does this occur in a new file as well.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add images that show what you are getting. ([read this link:](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491))

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. The OP says they see no encoding tab, and the answer to the proposed duplicate says "look at the encoding tab".... That is a non-answer in this situation. That being said, as others have pointed out, this question is not answerable due to a lack of details. Voting to close as unclear.

Comment: The encoding tab will only appear if FFmpeg is selected.